# Mysql syntax error creating stored function 5.6.10

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I am getting a syntax error on executing the below function in MySQL.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `WORKDAYS` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `WORKDAYS` (start_date DATETIME, end_date DATETIME) 
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN 
 DECLARE days INT; 
 SET days = 0;
 REPEAT
 SET days = days + (CASE WHEN DAYNAME(start_date) in ('Friday', 
                      'Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 0  ELSE 1 END);
 SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
 UNTIL start_date > end_date END  REPEAT;     
 RETURN days;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error I get: [ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN days;
END' at line 13

Comment: Error i get : [ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN days;
END' at line 13

Comment: Edit your question and add the full text of the error message

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thank you .. added the error message to the question

Comment: You're not actually running the sql with the `` before the first DELIMITER statement and after the last one, are you?

Comment: Without actually testing it, the only think I see is the ```END $$```. Add a line break before the ```$$```.Shoudn't matter, but worth a try.

Comment: @Uueerdo no `` is not part of the query.

Comment: Got rid of $$ next to end and it worked just fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just checked the syntax and found an odd character that displays as a space. Cleaned up the spaces and it checked out fine. I'll post an answer with the cleaned text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden character in your query after the `END REPEAT;`. Make sure your editor is UTF-8.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `WORKDAYS`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `WORKDAYS` (start_date DATETIME, end_date DATETIME) 
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN 
    DECLARE days INT; 
    SET days = 0;
    REPEAT
        SET days = days + (CASE WHEN DAYNAME(start_date) in ('Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
        SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    UNTIL start_date > end_date END REPEAT;
RETURN days;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for cleaning out the query @Sloan Thrasher